# Weird bug when I try to make calls from the eSIM with a Galaxy Watch 5 Pro LTE

Tags: android-wear, wearable

So this has been bugging me for awhile. I have a Galaxy Watch 5 Pro LTE that runs Wear OS 3.5. I have an eSIM set up with one number and the watch is paired with my dual SIM phone that only has one SIM in it.

I want to make calls with either SIM from the phone, so I have set-up "Preferred number" to "Always ask" in the Phone app settings. **Normally, this shows an activity with two buttons when I make a call - one for the phone and another for the watch. But a few days ago the watch started showing THREE buttons instead of two - one for the phone and TWO for the watch (see attached image).**

[image: Three buttons when trying to make a call, two of them for the watch.]

The problem is that neither of them work! They either do nothing or show the activity for dialing but the watch doesn't make a call. The "phone" button works as expected.

If I disconnect from the phone the watch makes calls. If I set my preferred number to "Watch" the calls also work. **But if I have the phone connected and the preferred number is set to "Always ask", I can't make calls with the watch.**

I have tried rebooting the watch, updating to the latest firmware, updating all apps on the watch and on the phone, disabling and enabling the eSIM on the watch - nothing fixes the issue.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?